# Using Accounts on Linux via Virtualbox and Virtual Player

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am a Windows user and Linux user. Usually, I use Windows for personal use like apps and accounts often but I tend to use Linux most of the time on a Windows operating system using Virtualbox more practically but considering becoming personal use with LinuxMint or Ubuntu.

Although Virtualbox is most considerable for practical use than personal use but I was just wondering if I used Linux on Virtualbox for personal use; would it be unsafe for logging into accounts such as facebook, google, etc. and using applications like Dropbox, Whatsapp, etc. is that considered safe or unsafe?